# URL embedded with <a href= in PDF file not working

Tags: php, pdf, pdflib

I create PDF files with PHP using PDFlib. I am trying to print a new line with a link to an external website. Code snippet is:

```
     $slilink = 'a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/watkanaidoo/">link to LinkedIn page /a>';
     //(I leave off the preceding '<' notation to display correctly here)
     $ly = $ly + 12;
     pdf_show_xy($pdf, "", 12, $ly);
     pdf_show_xy($pdf, "", 100, $ly);
     pdf_show_xy($pdf, "", 180, $ly);
     pdf_show_xy($pdf, $slilink, 320, $ly);
```

This displays in the PDF a line showing the whole field, including the <a href characters. The link is clickable.

If I leave off the `<a href=` then the URL shows correctly, but is not clickable!

Answer (score 0):

PDFlib is not an HTML to PDF converter, so no HTML elements are converted directly.

However, you can of course create link annotations.

- First create an action with `create_action()`,
- and then use `fit_textline()` to output the text. There you specify the matchbox option with a name in the option list.
- This will calculate the required space for the text as a matchbox and you can then apply the link annotation with `create_annotation()` to this matchbox.

So possible code fragment looks like:

```
/* Create URI action */
$optlist = "url={https://www.linkedin.com/in/watkanaidoo/}";
$act = $pdf->create_action("URI", $optlist);

$pdf->fit_textline('link to LinkedIn page', 320, $y, "matchbox {name=link}");

/* Create Link annotation on matchbox "link" */
$optlist = "action={activate " . $act . 
    "} linewidth=0 usematchbox={link}";
$pdf->create_annotation(0, 0, 0, 0, "Link", $optlist);
```

(see also https://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/textflow/weblink_in_text/php/)

Please note, for text output I would recommend the much more powerful `fit_textline()` function instead of `show_xy()`.

The functional PDFlib API (deprecated since PDFlib 8) will
be removed in the next PDFlib major version in favor of the object-oriented interface. Therefore I have adapted the code example accordingly.

Comment: Rainer - thanks for this, but unfortunately my host server runs PDFlib Lite, and it doesn't support this code. Any ideas?

Comment: this code also works with the outdated and limited PDFlib 7 Lite. What you have to do is to use the old prefix based interface instead of the OOP one. (i.e. `PDF_ ` instead of `$pdf->`). Both `fit_textline()` and matchboxes also work with PDFlib 7 Lite. 
Please note, however, that PDFlib 7 has already reached EOL in October 2011. You do not want to use this version on a publicly available system anymore.